# AUC vs.Class imbalance in both training data and test data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, prediction, auc, model-evaluation

I have three datasets as below. They are about the same prediction task.

Data 1:

- Training data: 95% positive instances and 5% negative instances
- Test data: 95% positive instances and 5% negative instances

Data 2:

- Training data: 50% positive instances and 50% negative instances
- Test data: 50% positive instances and 50% negative instances

Data 3:

- Training data: 5% positive instances and 95% negative instances
- Test data: 5% positive instances and 95% negative instances

I use logistic regression to fit the three datasets respectively. I use the [AUC function](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score) provided by scikit-learn to measure the prediction outcome.

Surprisingly, the AUC of the Data 1 is 0.92, the AUC of the Data 2 is 0.75, the AUC fo the Data 3 is 0.68.

**Why does the AUC monotonically decrease? Is there any possible reason? I would like to have some kinds of numbers to prove the reason.**

========================================================================
Below is some descriptive analysis about the prediction

```
Data 1: TRUTH: 
AUC: 0.925431817577
CLASS 1:
prediction mean: 0.999236699597 # This is the mean of the prediction outcomes which in fact are in class 1.
prediction std: 0.00360159690023
CLASS 0:
prediction mean: 0.993764261308
prediction std: 0.0198596992508
Effect Size of the two groups: 0.18829037121178865

Data 2: TRUTH: 
AUC: 0.755869422091
CLASS 1:
prediction mean: 0.953888184569
prediction std: 0.0538778221966
CLASS 0:
prediction mean: 0.908878619149
prediction std: 0.0738915897689
Effect Size of the two groups: 0.3286908171245826

Data 3: 
AUC: 0.681406318885
CLASS 1:
prediction mean: 0.121257041956
prediction std: 0.090470866846
CLASS 0:
prediction mean: 0.070718980391
prediction std: 0.0579126148936
Effect Size of the two groups: 0.31566692944753133
```

**It seems that the effect sizes tell me the difference of the predictions in the Data 3 is more significant than that in the Data 2. However, the AUC of Data 1 is higher. This makes me very confused.**

The distributions of the prediction outcomes are as below:
[image]

Zoom in the upper left corner.
[image]

Below is the ROC. I still do not understand why the ROC of data 1 is the best.

[image][image][image]

Comment: From your description, it appears you are fitting a model to each dataset and then computing AUC on on the same dataset. In other words, no cross-validation is occurring. (Is that correct? Or is the AUC you report the average over k-fold cross-validation?) Unfortunately, without cross-validation, all the AUC tells us is the tendency of the model to over fit. I encourage you to repeat your experiment and calculate AUC using cross-validation. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc_crossval.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was abandoned by the OP after a request for clarification.